# How to Add Items to Folder Redirect Without Anyone Else Having Access?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, folder-redirection

I'm working on an AD domain with about 70 users.  There is a folder redirect for everyone to have the same desktop.  However, one specific user wants a folder on her desktop that nobody should have access to (she's the office manager).  Is there way way to put a folder on her desktop without anyone seeing it?  I mean, I can set specific permissions on that folder, but that seems super roundabout.  And ultimately incredibly inefficient if it's multiple items they want to put on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are redirected folders that are accessible from a Share, you can make use of ABE (Access Based Enumeration) on that Share to prevent users who don't have NTFS permissions on that particular folder from seeing it. This requires you to set the permissions on that particular folder appropriately, which BTW, isn't a round about way of securing a folder.

Comment: It's absolutely not a roundabout way of securing a folder, but I meant it's roundabout to do it for multiple items (that was, of course, assuming there was an easier way to do it).

Comment: If it were me, and this is just my opinion, I'd use NTFS and ABE to secure and hide the folders in question.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up where 'all users' desktop is folder redirected to the 'one for all' desktop.  Then each user's profile desktop folder can either be local or redirected to a folder specifically for them.  When windows loads a user profile, it combines the all user profile with the user profile and displays the union of the two.

Switching to this kind of setup would be more complicated than what you've got, but it would be closer in line with common practices and it would give the end-users some customizability, if that is desirable.  The items that are common to all, like links, are easy.  Common items that are modified are easy too.  But adding new items would most easily be done in a folder on the desktop.  Otherwise, users could also browse the "all users\desktop" and add/modify files there.